# in my linux server, I got an php error, but I can not see the error, why?

Tags: php, linux, apache, yii, phpexcel

My php code (which is a exporting pdf and excel feature, and I'm using Yii framework) is working well in my local machine.
But when I put the code in the linux server, 
I get an error. I use echo to debug it step by step, finally I found it failed in this step. $objWriter->save('php://output'); (which is using PHPExcel).

but I'm not able to see what error it is.

I set the display_errors = On, and also set the error_log.
but I'm still not able to see the error information.

Comment: don't forget [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)

Comment: The actual error is probably a permission problem

Comment: have you checked the logs files? it is a shared hosting? if so, you can go to the control panel, there should be an utility to show access/error logs (php, apache, and so) Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have these set:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // or possibly: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('scream.enabled', TRUE); // this overrides the @ operator
```

If you want any error to halt the execution of the script then define an error handler function:

```
function my_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext) {
    file_put_contents(
        'custom_log_file.log',
        '#'.$errno.' '.$errfile.':'.$errline.' '.$errstr
    );
    // throw new Exception('#'.$errno.' '.$errfile.':'.$errline.' '.$errstr);
    die('#'.$errno.' '.$errfile.':'.$errline.' '.$errstr);
}
set_error_handler('my_error_handler');
```

If you choose to throw exceptions from your error handler function (which most likely you won't be expecting to catch just - they're just for debug purposes) you can setup an exception handler.

```
function my_exception_handler() {
     // here you code some nice visuals for your error handling
}
set_exception_handler('my_exception_handler');
```

In both cases you can `var_dump(debug_backtrace());` to see the data context in which the error occurred.

If the PHP file is the first visited (i.e. it's URL is in the address bar of the browser) and it has a syntax error in it then no-error reporting mechanism show that error.

You can use the linux CLI `php -l filename.php` to check for syntax errors in a file. Or you can create another file x.php containing just an include to `filename.php`.

Comment: try 
        {
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo '12';
        }

Comment: and I also tried error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('scream.enabled', TRUE);

Comment: If the PHP file is the first visited (i.e. it's URL is in the address bar of the browser) and it has a syntax error in it then no-error reporting mechanism show that error.

Comment: The most obvious causes for this are out of memory or time exceeded errors: what does the web server log show?

Comment: @Mark if he is using error_reporting / display_errors - time/memory exceeded errors will always be shown. The only errors not shown are syntax errors in the first file.

Comment: @Mihai - as the script is generating an output file (save to php://output), headers should already have been sent advising the browser that the file content is going to be an Excel file... do time/memory errors get displayed in the browser window in this case?

Comment: Depends, if the Excel file triggers a file-download dialogue then the "page-view" **is** the resulting file. If you download it and open it with a text editor or `cat filename.xls` into the command line you will see the errors. If it doesn't generate the file-download dialogue then it gets displayed into the browser and among the binary garbage you'll see the error messages.

Comment: @MihaiStancu Thanks for your answers. now I see the error, I guess it's a brower issue. today I use HttpAnalyzer to check the http request. apparently the error information are all in the response. I guess, maybe because of the content-type. firefox and chrome are all redirect to the 404 not found page. I think if I removed the line header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); the error should display in the brower.

Comment: @MarkBaker now I got the real error message information, I think I can hand it now. date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Moscow' for 'MSD/4.0/DST' instead